# Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-integration-ognl:bundle:2.0.2

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-mina, artifact

I have my own JAR configured in local Maven repository which depends on MINA in the following way:

```xml
<!-- mina-core-2.0.2.jar -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
  <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I wrote this hoping Maven will download  JARs of version 2.0.2 as my library requires.

But 2.0.2 artifacts were recognized by Eclipse as "bundles".

The `mina-integration-jmx` artifact depends on `mina-integration-ognl` in the following way

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

i.e. it wishes `mina-integration-ognl` to be a bundle.

I see this artifact in repositories and see no problems why it can be not downloaded.

**My Entire POM**

This POM was used to create `org.red5:red5` artifact:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.red5</groupId>
  <artifactId>red5</artifactId>
  <name>Red5 Library</name>
  <version>1.0.0-RC1</version>
  <description>Red5 Core Library</description>
  <dependencies>




<!-- com.springsource.slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- com.springsource.org.apache.xerces-2.9.1.jar -->

<!-- mina-core-2.0.2.jar -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
  <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang-2.4.0.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jaudiotagger-1.0.8.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jaudiotagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- logback-classic-0.9.26.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.26</version>
</dependency>

<!-- logback-core-0.9.26.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- httpclient-3.1.0.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- bcprov-jdk16-145.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.45</version>
</dependency>

<!-- xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- com.springsource.org.codehaus.groovy-1.7.0.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jython-2.5.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Dependencies were derived with JarAnalyzer from red5.jar, then red5.jar was installed into local repository.

Later in my Eclipse project this artifact was referred with the following POM:

```xml
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.red5</groupId>
    <artifactId>red5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your not actually putting the artifact `mina-integration-ognl` in your own POM file are you? Can you paste your entire POM.xml?

Comment: Does the mina-integration-ognl pom specify the good type (bundle) ?

Comment: @ramsinb I think it takes dependency on `mina-integration-ognl` from repository, not from me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use JarAnalyzer... Have run `mvn install` on your red5 project? Can you try that first and then go into your eclipse project and try building again?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following plugin to pom.xml project/build/plugins

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Great, this fixed my pom.xml :-)

Comment: It did fix it for me as well but it would be nice to understand why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with manual installing, I mean **mvn install** 
This is because maven couldn't download some dependencies automatically. So we have to use manual way to download dependencies with cmd.
this is another example with installing ojdbc14.jar

[How to add oracle jdbc jar to maven local repository](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the some Missing artifact errors in my pom, including your "Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-integration-ognl:bundle:" when using mina-integration-jmx. I can't say for sure this will work for for your situation but if you checkout the below example project into Eclipse, putting my  tag at the end of my broken pom, fixes these errors.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/mina/branches/2.0/mina-example

Here is the build tag I put at the end of my pom.

```
<build>
    <finalName>mina-game-server</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <!--  控制资源文件的拷贝
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
     -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- 设置源文件编码方式 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 打包jar文件时，配置manifest文件，加入lib包的jar依赖 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.example.bin.StartUp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 拷贝依赖的jar包到lib目录 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 解决资源文件的编码问题 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 解决mina包maven配置文件报错问题 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've tested the examples and they work.

If you're interested in my first half the pom I made for the mina-examples project, here is is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.shirong</groupId>
<artifactId>mina-example</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>  
<name>Apache MINA Examples</name>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
  <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-xbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-statemachine</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-filter-compression</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-transport-apr</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jmock</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

gl